# How to use MagickGetImageHistogram of ImageMagick C API

Tags: c, lua, imagemagick, ffi, luajit

I have been using ImageMagick's C API using LuaJIT and FFI library and [magick](https://github.com/leafo/magick) lua module for this. Now I want to use [MagickGetImageHistogram](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickGetImageHistogram) method. So when it comes to pass an argument check my below code.

```
***image.lua***

local len = ffi.new("size_t[?]", 5)
local t = handle_result(self, lib.MagickGetImageHistogram(self.wand, len))

***lib.lua***

local ffi = require("ffi")
local lib
ffi.cdef([[  typedef void MagickWand;
typedef void PixelWand;

typedef int MagickBooleanType;
typedef int ExceptionType;
typedef int ssize_t;
typedef int CompositeOperator;
typedef int GravityType;
typedef int OrientationType;
typedef int InterlaceType;
typedef char DistortMethod[];

void MagickWandGenesis();
MagickWand* NewMagickWand();

PixelWand **MagickGetImageHistogram(MagickWand *wand, size_t *number_colors);
```

So I'm sure that my first argument is correct but not sure about second one.
And it returns the image histogram as an array of PixelWand wands. So how do I convert it to LuaJIT structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) parts of the question, but the expected behavior `MagickGetImageHistogram` is as follows.

1. Method will return an array of pixel pointers.
2. Argument `size_t *number_colors` will be updated with the count of pixels in array.
3. Each pixel in array will need to invoke method `PixelGetColorCount` to retrieve the sum of pixels used by image.

Here's a quick example in C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Prototype vars
    MagickWand * wand;
    PixelWand ** histogram;
    size_t histogram_count = 0;
    // Boot environment.
    MagickWandGenesis();
    // Allocate & read image
    wand = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage(wand, "rose:");
    // Get Histogram as array of pixels
    histogram = MagickGetImageHistogram(wand, &histogram_count);
    // Iterate over each pixel & dump info.
    for (int i = 0; i < histogram_count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s => %zu\n",
               PixelGetColorAsString(histogram[i]),
               PixelGetColorCount(histogram[i]));
    }
    // Clean-up
    histogram = DestroyPixelWands(histogram, histogram_count);
    wand = DestroyMagickWand(wand);
    MagickWandTerminus();
    return 0;
}
```

This example will output the expected text...

```txt
// ...
srgb(48,45,43) => 1
srgb(50,45,42) => 2
srgb(50,44,43) => 5
srgb(51,45,43) => 1
// ...
```

So I would guess your lua script would look something like..

```lua
***image.lua***

local tlen = ffi.new("size_t[1]")
local t = lib.MagickGetImageHistogram(self.wand, tlen)
for i=0,tlen[0] do
    handle_new_pixel(self, t[i], lib.PixelGetColorCount(t[i]))
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot emcconville. When I run your c program, it gives me an outoput like you have mentioned. But in my lua I always get boolean true of local t = lib.MagickGetImageHistogram(self.wand, tlen), when I print local t.